# Local Storage - Same origin but different contents

Tags: javascript, webview, local-storage, microsoft-edge, outlook-addin

We have a really weird bug, which we suspect is specific to Edge Webview2 (based on Chromium).

We are developing an Outlook Add-In, on my machine Outlook has been upgraded to use the Edge Webview2 component instead of Edge Webview (based on Legacy Edge). During this upgrade it has broken our app.

When we investigated it, it appears that depending on the **page** the user is on, gives us different localStorage contexts, despite being the same origin - this all persists across restarting Outlook or closing the add-in. This is showcased in this screenshot:

[image: localStorage based on page instead of origin]

Is there anything we should look at to resolve or debug this?

NOTE: All other clients (Outlook for Web in all browsers, macOS Outlook, etc) do not have this issue.

Comment: As a note, we were able to workaround this issue by using `postMessage` to communicate between the two and used that to sync the `localStorage`, but that doesn't solve or discover the core problem

Comment: I test localStorage in WebView2 and it works well. Could you please provide [a code example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) which can **reproduce** the issue? Have you tried with Outlook for Web in Edge Chromium? WebView2 uses Edge Chromium as the rendering engine. If it works with Outlook for Web in Edge Chromium, then I think the issue might be related with the Outlook desktop client.

Comment: In Edge there should be a send feedback link in the tools menu for reporting bugs. Too bad Microsoft doesn't seem to have a way to publicly track Edge bugs.

Comment: Ironically the send feedback / report a problem buttons do not work in Webview2 that is used within Outlook, and I suspect this is a problem in the implementation of Webview2 in Outlook more than Webview2 itself. I did manage to lodge a support ticket with Microsoft via the partner portal, we'll see how that goes

Comment: That's good. You can also post here if you get any solutions. It can help other community members in future in similar kind of issues.

Answer (score 0):

The reason this happened is because the add-in had some how been marked for "debug" mode in the registry. There is a bug (/feature) that the panel will be in "debug" mode, but the dialogs launched from that panel will be in "regular" mode. The `user-data-dir` for each mode is a different directory, so this is effectively making it have isolated local / session storages.

To disable this debug mode, you can delete all the keys in:

```
Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\16.0\WEF\Developer
```

More information about this issue can be found in the Office JS issue tracker:

https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js/issues/1741

---

This particular debug feature, I cannot find any public documentation for nor do I know how it was enabled in the first place. This debug feature does not affect "Classic Edge" rendering engine.